# Will the second callback in then() be executed and why we need a throw statement?

Tags: javascript, promise, httprequest

I'm new to JavaScript and currently learning about Async JavaScript and HTTP Requests.

Here is the code that causes the confusion:

```js
fetch(url, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json",
    apikey: apiKey,
  },
  body: data,
})
  .then(
    (response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      }
      throw new Error("Request failed!");
    },
    (networkError) => {
      console.log(networkError.message);
    }
  )
  .then((jsonResponse) => {
    renderResponse(jsonResponse);
  });
```

Why is throw statement needed in the first callback in then(), since rejected case will be handled in the second callback?

I tried to ask chatgpt. It told me that when the program reaches the throw statement, then the second callback in then() will be executed, which made me more confused.

I appreciate it if someone could tell me the operating mechanism and the logic behind then() and its two callbacks.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Comment: The Fetch API doesn't return a rejected promise for unsuccessful responses, only lower level networking issues. I do not think this code is particular good, it will return a successful promise on network errors which resolves with `undefined`. Better to remove the 2nd `.then()` callback

Comment: "*rejected case will be handled in the second callback?*" however `response.ok = false` case is **not** going to be rejected. "*I tried to ask chatgpt. It told me that when the program reaches the throw statement, then the second callback in then() will be executed, which made me more confused.*" yes, it would be confusing, considering this is completely and utterly false. Rejecting in the `.then()` does *not* call the second callback. It will call further `.catch()` or a two argument `.then()` https://jsbin.com/jiheyibogu/1/edit?js,console

Comment: Have a look at the [difference between `.then(…, …)` and `.then(…).catch(…)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass two callbacks to `.then()` as in `.then(fn1, fn2)`, then ONLY ONE of them will get executed based on the state of the parent promise.  Throwing in fn1 will NOT cause fn2 to execute.

If you want your error handler to be executed when you `throw` in a `.then()` handler, then use a `.catch()` after it as in:

```
.then(fn1).catch(fn2)
```

In that case, throwing in `fn1` will cause `fn2` to execute.

> Why is throw statement needed in the first callback in then(),

In your specific example, the throw is to turn the case when `response.ok` is not true into a promise rejection.  `fetch()` by default only rejects when there's an actual network error.  A 400 or 500 status does not cause a rejection.  As far as `fetch()` is concerned, any response from the server, even a 4xx or 5xx response is considered "success" and results in a resolved promise, not a rejection.

So, the point of your `throw` is to turn those 4xx and 5xx cases into a rejection.  Of course, you don't have any code in your example that will catch that rejection because you don't show a subsequent `.catch()` or subsequent `.then()` with the second argument.

> since rejected case will be handled in the second callback?

Your `throw` won't be handle in your second callback.  And, a `!response.ok` won't be handled by your second callback either.

---

In my opinion, this whole issue of 4xx and 5xx responses not being a rejection is a primary benefit to using other libraries such as `axios()` or `got()` as it prevents you from having this extra code every time.  Of course, you could also make your own wrapper utility function that you use instead of `fetch()`.  In fact, I was bummed that nodejs was making the `fetch()` interface a standard interface because IMO this is a usability miss with the way this interface works.  It leads to either faulty code when people don't check and handle `!response.ok` or it results in extra code all the time to do so.  Libraries like `axios()` or `got()` are configurable in this regard with a default to reject upon 4xx and 5xx response.

Comment: [ky](https://github.com/sindresorhus/ky) is the browser-based equivalent to `got()` (same author). Axios IMO is hot garbage

Comment: @Phil - `got()` is my favorite and what I use in nodejs.  I mention `axios()` because it is used by a lot of developers (I'm not sure why).  I didn't know there was `ky()` in the browser.  Will have to remember that.